# iText 7 PDF signing with GlobalSign DSS

Tags: pdf, digital-signature, itext7

I'm digitally signing a PDF using iText 7 in an asp.net app. I'm using vb but I could figure out a c# answer, too.  We're using GlobalSign DSS in order to have the signature not come up as UNKNOWN (AATL).

I created a pfx file from our company SSL certificate and I am able to sign the PDF files using that file but I don't understand how to use the things I get from GlobalSign to accomplish the same thing.  This service requires to send a hex encoded SHA256 digest and in return I receive a hex encoded signatureValue. Besides that I also receive a PEM encoded X509 signing certificate, intermediate certificate (PEM encoded X509 certificate that represents the issuer of the signing certificate), Base64 encoded DER representation of the OCSP response for signing_certificate, a Base64 encoded DER representation of timestamp token. It includes the TSA signing certificate in SignedData.CertificatesSet.

I created the code below as best as I could with limited examples from the internet for itext 7 and my even more limited knowledge of PDF signing and certificates in general.  I know now that there are some things I make that I don't even use properly such as the tsaClient and the crlList.  I didn't quite understand what those were until I had to switch to the DSS.  I actually still don't know what the crlList would be although I think it has something to do with a chain, although I don't quite know what a chain is in this context.

```
Dim outputFileStream As New FileStream(Server.MapPath(strDest), IO.FileMode.Create, IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite)
Dim signer As New PdfSigner(New PdfReader(Server.MapPath(strTemp)), outputFileStream, True)

signer.SetCertificationLevel(PdfSigner.CERTIFIED_FORM_FILLING_AND_ANNOTATIONS)

Dim appearance As PdfSignatureAppearance = signer.GetSignatureAppearance
Dim rect As New iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle(50, 425, 500, 200)
appearance.SetContact("Contact Name - Phone")
appearance.SetSignatureCreator("Company - New Program")
appearance.SetReason(vbCrLf + "eDoc Consent Agreement: " + CType(Session("eDocConsentDateTime"), Date).ToString + vbCrLf _
                     + "Terms and Conditions Agreement: " + objInstall.AgreementSigned.ToString + vbCrLf _
                     + "Identifier: " + Session("Ident"))
appearance.SetLocation(vbCrLf + strInstallationAddress)
appearance.SetReuseAppearance(False)
appearance.SetPageRect(rect)
appearance.SetPageNumber(2)     'Signature will appear on Page 2
appearance.SetRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION)

signer.SetFieldName(signer.GetNewSigFieldName())

Dim cert As New X509Certificate(Server.MapPath("CompSSL.pfx"), "password")
Dim tsaUrl As String = CertificateUtil.GetTSAURL(DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(cert))
tsaClient = New TSAClientBouncyCastle(tsaUrl)
Dim crlList As IList(Of ICrlClient) = New List(Of ICrlClient)()

Dim fsCertFile As New FileStream(Server.MapPath("CompSSL.pfx"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
Dim pk12 As New Pkcs12Store(fsCertFile, "password")
fsCertFile.Dispose()

'then Iterate throught certificate entries to find the private key entry
Dim [alias] As String = Nothing
For Each tAlias As String In pk12.Aliases
  If pk12.IsKeyEntry(tAlias) Then
    [alias] = tAlias
    Exit For
  End If
Next
Dim pk = pk12.GetKey([alias]).Key

Dim myExternalSignature As IExternalSignature = New PrivateKeySignature(pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA1)

signer.SignDetached(myExternalSignature, New Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate() {pk12.GetCertificate([alias]).Certificate}, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, 0, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS)
```

So I'd like to know how I can use the GlobalSign pieces in order to sign the PDF.  It almost seems like they are giving me everything I need to plug into the SignDetached method at the very end but I specifically don't know these things:

1. I believe that I'm supposed to do the hash to create the digest AFTER I've added the appearance stuff but I don't know what I would pass those bytes to something like Dim hash() As Byte = s.ComputeHash(fileBytes) at that point in my code (right after signer.SetFieldName(signer.GetNewSigFieldName()) I assume)
2. I don't know how or if I use the two certificates I get from the DSS.  I even saw an example that suggests I may put them together to get something.
3. I don't know if the Signature Value I get is the equivalent of the IExternalSignature.  If so, I don't know how to convert it to type "Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.ICipherParameters" or even if I'm supposed to be trying to.
4. I plug the timestamp token string I get back from the DSS into the line tsaClient = New TSAClientBouncyCastle(tsaUrl) in the place of "tsaUrl" and there is no error but I don't know if that's right.
5. I don't know what to do with the OCSP response that I get from the DSS to put it into an IOcspClient object.
6. If I don't even try to put in the timestamp or the OCSP response in, as apparently I don't in the .pfx version of my code, what will that mean?
7. What are the data type conversions I'll have to do, if any, to make the DSS responses work?

I've tried to follow the iTextsharp examples, even this one ([itextsharp signing pdf with signed hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52952809/itextsharp-signing-pdf-with-signed-hash)) which is exactly what I'm trying to do but it doesn't seem to give me the info I need to finish it off. Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:**
Thanks for the help, dsandoval.  I went ahead and hash the unchanged file and that's what I send to GlobalSign:

```
Dim s As New SHA256Managed
Dim fileBytes() As Byte = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath(strSrc))
Dim hash() As Byte = s.ComputeHash(fileBytes)
Dim calculatedHash As String = ByteArrayToString(hash)
```

With this too:

```
Private Function ByteArrayToString(ByVal arrInput() As Byte) As String
  Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder(arrInput.Length * 2)
  For i As Integer = 0 To arrInput.Length - 1
    sb.Append(arrInput(i).ToString("X2"))
  Next
  Return sb.ToString().ToUpper
End Function
```

Then I wrote the two certificates I get from GS to files and then use BouncyCastle to read them into certificates and put them into an array (signing cert first).  I pick up where I am writing the second cert file from their 'certificate_path' string here:

```
Using sw As New StreamWriter(File.Open(strFile2, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
  sw.WriteLine(strTempCert2)
End Using
Dim fileStream2 = System.IO.File.OpenText(strFile2)
Dim pemReader2 = New Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemReader(fileStream2)
Dim myCertificateChain() As Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate = New Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate() {pemReader.ReadObject, pemReader2.ReadObject}
```

I did the same thing you did with IExternalSignature using this to convert the string from GS:

```
Private Function StringToByteArray(s As String) As Byte()
  ' remove any spaces from, e.g. "A0 20 34 34"
  s = s.Replace(" "c, "")
  ' make sure we have an even number of digits
  If (s.Length And 1) = 1 Then
    Throw New FormatException("Odd string length when even string length is required.")
  End If

' calculate the length of the byte array and dim an array to that
  Dim nBytes = s.Length \ 2
  Dim a(nBytes - 1) As Byte

  ' pick out every two bytes and convert them from hex representation
  For i = 0 To nBytes - 1
    a(i) = Convert.ToByte(s.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16)
  Next

  Return a
End Function
```

For now I'm just including the certificate chain and the signature and not the timestamp or the OCSP to see if I can just get it signed.  With the certificate chain and the implementation of IExternalSignature, I'm able to get SignDetached to run:

```
signer.SignDetached(myExternalSignature, myCertificateChain, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, 0, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS)
```

The PDF is signed but the signature panel says "Certification by is invalid", "Certified by %s".  The details say "There are errors in the formatting or information contained in this signature".  When clicking on "Certificate details", nothing happens.  I found another person online with this error ([Error signing pdf with PHP's openssl_pkcs7_sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47673663/error-signing-pdf-with-phps-openssl-pkcs7-sign/47802588#47802588)) and it was due to the signature container being too big.  The zero in my SignDetached parameters is supposed to be "estimate the size" so I changed it to 8192 which was a magic number of 8k I found in some other examples online.  That didn't help.  Any suggestions at this point?

Comment: Doesn't GlobalSign DSS support provide example code for using their api with common pdf libraries?

Comment: They did provide some examples but they are the itextsharp examples that you see  other examples from.  I am working with them also to work this out but they can't answer the questions I had either.  It seems like I'm right there but I can't figure out how to plug what they give me into the SignDetached method.

Comment: They've been reading Bruno's whitepaper (as I did also) but the section that seems helpful (sample 4.11) is in itext sharp.  I can't figure out pk, Certificate[] and digest as it pertains to itext 7.

Comment: I myself am not a GlobalSign DSS customer and, therefore, have not dealt with their APIs yet. [Here](https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/I7JS/repos/signatures/browse/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/signatures) you can find the ports of the whitepaper examples to iText 7 / Java. Based on this you merely have to port to .Net. One hint, though: The examples requiring a private key locally most likely aren't what you need as I assume that GlobalSign won't give you that key but require you to send them data or hashes to sign for which they return signatures.

Comment: Here is a link to two PDFs before and after the signature https://drive.google.com/open?id=1drB2Z3MWgX1IKRF8yLtGCGwoEmK_EbMh

Comment: You are aware that the PDF 'before' has completely different contents from the PDF 'after'? Furthermore you appear to use iText 7.0.2.2. I'd propose you update to the current 7.1.x version as anyone answering would expect you use that version.

Comment: If the GlobalSign DSS API has a function/service that requires a hash value as parameter and returns a CMS signature container, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57168641/1729265) may be of interest for you.

Comment: Concerning the `066_20190813_141324490_SIGNED.PDF` example - there is a CMS signature container embedded alright... but where the actual signature bytes in it should be, there is merely a copy of the authenticated bytes, i.e. the bytes which should have been hashed and signed...

Comment: Sorry the files weren't the same.  I ran across a thread where there was problems when after updating a pdf form, it wouldn't sign correctly. I tried to test mine on a plain pdf with no form fields and no editing done.  I forgot to switch it back out.  I'm a little bit further now because I changed the IExternalSignature class to be more like the examples you all have provided.  Now I actually have a signature on the SIGNED pdf that says our certificate name.  Now it just says that it's been modified since signing.

Comment: Of course, I also upgraded to itext 7.1.7 which required BouncyCastle 1.8.1.3 or greater.  So I went with BC 1.8.5 but every time I started the program it would error out saying that it was looking for 1.8.1.0.  I'm not great at figuring that stuff out so I just replaced the 1.8.5 dll with the old one.  Not before I spent several hours on trying to figure out how to do it right.  I think I still have a problem with the signature bytes so I'm looking at how to do that different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using c# for my implementation. I'm not too familiar with VB but hopefully this helps. Most of the examples I've seen are using Java and there were some differences in how they implement this, so I had to work around them. The only things I had to implement for this work was the IExternalSignature, IOcspClient, and ITsaClient.

1. The digest that is sent to GlobalSign are the contents of the document prior to applying to the signature, so the appearance can be left out if applied with signature. The document is not modified until you apply the signature using the PdfSigner.SignDetached, I believe. To compute the digest, you need to use the SHA256 algorithm to hash the message and hexencode it. This is the digest that will be sent to GS.
2. You need to put both the certificates from GlobalSign to create the certificate chain. First add the signing certificate then the certificate you can retrieve from their 'certificate_path' endpoint.
3. I'm not sure about the conversion to that type, but with the c# library, the Sign method of IExternalSignature returns a byte[]. With my own implementation of the interface, I simply converted the SignatureValue we received from GS to a byte[].
4. For the timestamp, we also implemented our own ITsaClient that calls GS for the timestamp. The digest has to be calculated in the GetTimeStampToken method and sent to GS. The response is a hexencoded string that we convert to a byte[].
5. For the OCSP, we also implemented our own IOcspClient. Since we get the ocsp_response when we fetch the identity, this client simply uses that, rather than calling GS again. I had issues enabling LTV when returning the response by only converting it from a Base64 string to a byte[]. BouncyCastle had trouble reading the response in this format. I had to convert it to the following BouncyCastle objects for this to work properly.

   ```cs
   public byte[] GetEncoded( X509Certificate checkCert, X509Certificate issuerCert, string url )
   {
       var decoded = Base64.Decode(_ocspResponse); //_ocspResponse is same one that we received when fecthing the identity
       var response = new OcspResp(decoded);
       var basicResponse = (BasicOcspResp)response.GetResponseObject();

       return basicResponse.GetEncoded();
   }
   ```
6. If no timestamp is attached, the signature will not be timestamped. It will display the time as something along the lines of "the time is time on the signer's computer's system clock" when you open the document in Adobe. If no ocsp response is attatched, the person validating will not have a way to validate that the certificate has/hasn't been revoked at the time of the signature.
7. I believe the only conversions I had to make were the one mentioned above.

Let me know if you need any more code examples or any other questions.

**EDIT**

Here is the IExternalSignature implementation. The hash and encryption algorithm has to match what GS will use. They are using SHA256 and RSA.

```cs
public class ExternalSignature : IExternalSignature
{
    private readonly SigningIdentity _identity;
    private readonly GlobalSignClient _client;
    public ExternalSignature( GlobalSignClient client, SigningIdentity identity )
    {
        _client = client;
        _identity = identity;
    }

    public string GetEncryptionAlgorithm() => "RSA";

    public string GetHashAlgorithm() => DigestAlgorithms.SHA256;

    public byte[] Sign( byte[] message )
    {
        // Using the System.Security.Cryptography implementation of SHA256
        using (var sha = SHA256.Create())
        {
            // Hash the message, containing the PDF
            var bytes = sha.ComputeHash(message);
            // HexEconde the hashed message to send to GlobalSign   
            var digest = Helpers.ByteArrayToString(bytes);
            // Send the digest to GlobalSign
            var signature = _client.GetSignatureAsync(_identity.Id, digest).Result;
            // Return the returned signature as a byte[]
            return Helpers.StringToByteArray(signature);
        }
    }
}
```

To add the signature, just create an instance and pass it to SignDetached method.

```cs
var signature = new ExternalSignature(_client, signingIdentity);
...
...
//After creating the PDF signer, adding appearance, creating the OCSP and TSA clients.
signer.SignDetached(signature, certChain, null, ocsp, tsa, 0, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

I did the same with the OCSP and TSA clients.

Comment: Can you send me the implementation you have of IExternalSignature? And then how you use it to put it into the parameter for SignDetached?  I can only think that I'm doing that wrong or I'm doing the hash wrong in some way.  Thanks

Comment: I've added an example of my implementation.

Comment: Thanks, this helped out so now I actually can see the certificate info on the signature panel.  Now it just comes up as modified after signature.  The "message" that you send in for signature.sign are the file bytes of the Source file, right?  The one that is the PDFReader in your PDFSigner object?  And in the code above, you create "signature = new ExternalSignature".  Do you just call signature.sign after that and then SignDetached?

Comment: Also, your last parameter in SignDetached, "append".  Do you have that True or false?  I did my signatures with the PFX file with True but the example I saw has "false".

Comment: Yes, the message are the file bytes from the PDF reader. But there is no need to call the sign method as it will get called by the SignDetached method. That method will apply the signature to the document and close the document using the ExternalSignature. The same goes for the OcspClient and TsaClient. That should be the last method you call.

Comment: I'm using this version of the library. The method doesn't have an "append" parameter but I do set append to true by using the stampingProperties in the constructor.
 https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/7.1.7/com/itextpdf/signatures/PdfSigner.html

Comment: Ok!  I didn't grasp the concept that signDetached was calling the sign method and was hashing the file in the sign method instead of hashing the "message" parameter.  Thank you and mkl for your help.  I'll provide my code to GlobalSign so they have a vb.net and iText 7 example to provide in the future.